# Object not draw properly in openGl Es

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am drawing the 3D object but its not drawing correctly. Original 3D file does not have diagonally but When I am drawing then its showing the diagonal. Please help me to why its drawing the diagonal.

See this link : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4plC.png

Code

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    //gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glDrawArrays(3, 0, v.size()/3);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    model.loadGLTexture(gl, context);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);    
    gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);            
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);         
    gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST); 
    gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);            
}

/**
 * Here we do our drawing
 */
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    //Clear Screen And Depth Buffer
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);    
    gl.glLoadIdentity();            
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0); //Move down 1.2 Unit And Into The Screen 6.0
    gl.glRotatef(xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   //X
    gl.glRotatef(yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);   //Y
    model.draw(gl);                     //Draw the square

    xrot += xspeed;
    yrot += yspeed;

}

/**
 * If the surface changes, reset the view
 */
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    if(height == 0) {                       //Prevent A Divide By Zero By
        height = 1;                         //Making Height Equal One
    }

    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);     //Reset The Current Viewport
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);    //Select The Projection Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Projection Matrix

    //Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, width/height, 0.1f, 500.0f);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);     //Select The Modelview Matrix
    gl.glLoadIdentity();                    //Reset The Modelview Matrix
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check the exact order of the vertices in vertexBuffer.
If the order jumped over the diagonal way on the rectangle, it will draw the diagonal line.

Comment: I could not get you 100%. Please help me just editing my code where is the problem..

Comment: I have uploaded the complete code and obj files in asset folder of project. Please find the project here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ejhlmgb86b05wv2/objLoader.rar  ..Please help me its not drawing correct object. Diagonal line appear and many distortion with mess inside the object. I could not recognize the where is the problem since last 4 days..raising hands for help

Comment: Sorry, I can't give you a consultation. This is "question and answer" web site. If you post the data on this thread and ask me what's wrong. Then I could answer back to you if I found something wrong. So please post the particular polygon data here. Otherwise, I can't help you.